# M2 – Mixed up languages in production mode

Tags: magento-2.1, production-mode

Site is a clean Magento 2.1.5 install. It’s a multistore setup with 4 languages: Dutch, French, German and English. Products are imported via csv. All working smoothly. Running my site in developer mode works fine. All sites have their own language without problems. The problem starts with going to production mode.

Running de command: `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` also goes smoothly without errors. After the command everything is compiled and  deployed, website is running fast and without problems, or not?

During compilation all carts and checkout pages are in German and not anymore in their own Dutch, French and Englisch language. Deploy language in developer mode works without problem, swithing to production mode, they are messed up.

All other pages and content stay in their own language except cart and checkout.

Is there a solution to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it with below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US de_DE fr_FR
```

Let me know if not working for you.

Comment: These commands works fine as long as the website is in developer mode.

As soon as we are in production mode, cart and checkout are in German and the rest of the website is in their own language. So it looks like the deployment of static content works okay with the exception of cart and checkout.

Does the order of languages in the static content deploy command have any impact on the end result?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround at the end.

In developer mode

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB de_DE fr_FR nl_NL
```

is doing the job

In production mode there is a strange behavior. All cart/checkout pages are deployed in the latest language in the command (nl_NL in this case)

Workaround:
set production mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

next steps:
Clear cache

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/*
```

upgrade and compile

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

deploy all languages seperate:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL 

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE 

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR 

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

Clear cache again